# React Native Expo, how to make call to a local API that has a self-signed certificate?

Tags: react-native, ssl, expo

We are developing a React Native App using Expo.

I'm having issues making HTTPS calls to the API running in my local machine where the emulator is running. HTTP API calls haven't been an issue, but I can't connect to the HTTPS API with a self-signed certificate.

The error happens on `fetch()`

`Network request failed`

I'm able to access the swagger for the API from the emulator's browser. It just shows like it has an invalid certificate.

In the Android Emulator I tried installing a CA certificate, but it didn't work.

Update with some code:

```
    // Android URL
    let url = `https://10.0.2.2:44387/api/auth/authpolicy/hasaccess`
    let headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`
        }
    let response = await fetch(url, { 'GET', headers })

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong getting Client Service Line Access Authorization')
    }
```

Comment: could you provide some code

Comment: Hello ErickM, did you figure it out?

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding _"In the Android Emulator I tried installing a CA certificate, but it didn't work."_?